# Getting error from bq tool when uploading and importing data on BigQuery - 'Backend Error'

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting the error: `BigQuery error in load operation: Backend Error` when I try to upload and import data on BQ. I already reduced size, increased time between imports, but nothing helps. The strange thing is that if I wait for a time and retry it just works.

In the BigQuery Browser tool it appears like an error in some line/field, but I checked and there is none. And obviously this is a fake message, because if I wait and retry to upload/import the same file, it works.

Tnks

Comment: Can you send the name of a job that failed (eg. job_<guid>) ? It should show in bq when you start the import, or bq ls -j should show job ids for failed jobs as well.

Comment: One of them is job_ff366bf61ee84f779dd0d8ba91589d7e

Answer (score 0):

I looked up our failing jobs in the bigquery backend, and I couldn't find any jobs that terminated with 'backend error'. I found several that failed because there were ascii nulls found in the data. (it can be helpful to look at the error stream errors, not just the error result). It is possible that the data got garbled on the way to bigquery... are you certain the data did not change between the failing import and the successful one on the same data?

Comment: I'm sending compressed GZIP files with tabular(\t) delimited fields and the data doesn't change, I just try to send the same file again and sometimes it works. I will try to upload the file with gs tool to google storage and then load it to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I've found exporting from a big query table to csv in cloud storage hits the same error when certain characters are present in one of the columns (in this case a column storing the raw results from a prediction analysis).  By removing that column from the export it resolved the issue.